# Closing AlertDialog.Builder in Android

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

In the following code, I tried to dismiss the `AlertDialog` box but to no avail. However, if I remove `compareKeys()` function, the dismiss will work. So how can I make it dismiss after calling the `compareKeys()` function?

```
public void promptAdministratorPassword() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Alert!");
    alert.setMessage("Please enter your password: ");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            password = input.getText().toString();

            if (password.equals("password")) {
                try {
                    compareKeys();
                } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.
        }
    });
    alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `dialog.dismiss()` before `password = input.getText().toString()` and add `dialog.dismiss()` inside `setNegativeButton`'s `OnClickListener` too.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciated your help!

Comment: The dismiss button work if it doesnt match the password, how do i dismiss it when it matches the password ? As of now, it will dismiss when i enter wrong password. But it will not dismiss when i enter correct password.